# Visual Basic Program acting odd

Tags: vb.net

Before i start explaining my problem, i want to make clear that i'm no programming expert and nor do i claim to be great, i just made a VB program for fun

Now... the question... so i made this program where it converts text into Discord emoji text, the solution does seem to be functional and works as it should no problems until i go above two lines of code in the text conversion part because when i do that the program outputs incorrect and messed up text, sometimes it will convert 2 letters into thousands of letters and i can't figure out why, sometimes it freezes and then displays the OutofMemory exception

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("a", ":regional_indicator_a: ")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("b", ":regional_indicator_b: ")
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("c", ":regional_indicator_c: ")
    Form3.Refresh()
    Form3.Show()
    Form3.TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have examples of the text in TextBox1 that both does and does not cause the problem you describe?

Comment: Do you have an event handler for the text changed event or similar? The out of memory exception in particular suggests you have some sort of repeated event triggering going on

Comment: 1.`Refresh` method only re-paint the form,it has nothing to do with updating the visual or some data of the form | 2.You have out of memory exception which indicates one or more method/function is being executed too many times | 3. Provide an image of the problem so that we can really see what's going on | 4.U replace `a` with `something` , how many `a` do u have in your textbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing an unintentional nested loop on each replaces after the first one as each line tries to replace text that was already changed on previous lines.

try to change the text characters like this as it is a character replacement of a single entry.

```
    Dim out = ""
    For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text
        out += ":regional_indicator_" + c + ": "
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = out
```

the last line changes the `TextBox1.Text` itself, and if you want to put "out" to somewhere else, change that line.

by the way, I don't know why you try to `Refresh()` and `Show()` the form again, but if you have to, then put those 2 lines AFTER textbox assignment, not before.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i'm a total baboon when it comes to programming, programming was never really my thing anyway i was just bored and i thought i'd mess around with vb.net a little

Comment: you don't need to belittle yourself. after all, we all begin like this before becoming pros. if you like programming, then having these kinds of problems will always be on your way. then you will learn to solve yourself at some point when you become familiar with coding. by the way, VB is a nice starting language for a beginner but also becomes very powerfull if you learn more, have fun with it.